# Calculate Yield [%] of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the yield of a process performance - in column "Value".

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['2020-08', 63], ['2020-08', 37], ['2020-08', 48], ['2020-09', 66], ['2020-09', 100], ['2020-09', 88]]  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Value']) 
df2
```

The specification is: 40 - 90.
The correct answer is a yield of 66,6%.

I really have no idea how to calculate the yield in an easy way.

```
df2['Value_Out_Low'] = df2['Value'] < 40
df2['Value_Out_High'] = df2['Value'] > 90
```

I wanted to merge them, then count "False" values and calculate the yield.
Is there any way how to calculate the yield from a column within given specifications?

Comment: what is the formula for calculating this 'yield'? a sample calculation would be most helpful

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
import numpy as np
res = (df2['Value'] <40) | (df2['Value'] > 90)
yield_val = 1 - np.count_nonzero(res) / np.size(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not need numpy for this, can do simply

```
1 - sum((df2['Value'] <40) | (df2['Value'] > 90))/len(df)
```